# How to set some view controller in landscape mode and some other in portrait by default

Tags: swift, uiinterfaceorientation, landscape-portrait

How to set some view controller in landscape mode and some other in portrait by default.No need to rotate.I need it as landscape only or portrait only.

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

    return false

}



override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {

    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.rawValue)

}
```

For portrait

```
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {

    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)

}
```

It cannot work porperly

Am using xcode 6.4. ios 8

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
}
```

> Asks the delegate for the interface orientations to use for the view
>   controllers in the specified window

Comment: Thank you.Thats work.But when launch it some times give landscape screen width and height for portriat view. Ex: for portriat width 1024 and 798 instead of 798 ,1024 width height.Why it happens like this.

Comment: Where do you get these numbers from?

Comment: i just print self.view.frame.size when view loads

Comment: becuase i create buttons depend on view size so when it changes the button position also replaces.Some times view display correctly but some time not

Comment: Did you print this in viewDidAppear() or viewDidLoad()?

Comment: viewDiLoad.And another information my segues are in programatically not using storybord

Comment: Have you defined you preferred orientation that the VC should be in when it gets presented? override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation It should be the same as your supportedInterfaceOrientation()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89566/discussion-between-lydia-and-valentin).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Main.Storyboard then go to your attribute inspector and change the device orientation to the orientation you want.
You can uncheck if user can change orientation or not.